# cakephp value isnt sent to action

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following action:

```
    public function admin_website_status($id = null){
    $i = 0;

    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'Website' => array(
        )
    );
    $this->set('websites',$this->Paginator->paginate('Website'));
}
```

Now i want to send a value to this action so in my view i have the following link:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Active'), array('action' => 'website_status', $website['Website']['website_id'])); ?>
```

When i debug this no value is sent even though i know that the value should be `1`

So what am i doing wrong?

**My full view**

```
<div class="portlet box red">
<div class="portlet-title">
    <div class="caption"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Website Status</div>
</div>
<div class="portlet-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Website.domain', 'Website domain');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Website.client_id', 'Affiliate ID');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('User.username', 'E-mail Address');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Status.status', 'Status'); ?> </th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($websites as $site): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $site['Website']['domain']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $site['Client']['client_id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $site['Client']['user_id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $site['Status']['Status']; ?></td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Active'), array('action' => 'website_status', $website['Website']['website_id'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <div class="paging">
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$websites['Website']['website_id']
```

and not

```
$website['Website']['website_id']
```

(plural and not singular)

edit: after seeing your whole code

```
$site['Website']['website_id']
```

Comment: This is not the issue i will post my full view here so you can see.. The link is being generated in a loop

Comment: SOOO fail i just realized the problem is that its not $website its $site! you were right!

Comment: so: `$site['Website']['website_id']`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `$this->Html->link` you set `'action' => 'website_status'`
Is it supposed to be admin_website_status ?

Also make sure `$website['Website']['website_id']` has a value. Maybe it is empty.

Comment: i am 100 % sure that it has a value since i can debug it.

Comment: SOOO fail i just realized the problem is that its not $website its $site! you were right! Sorry! do you know how i can send two values instead of one?